# VB.Net Differences between some functions

Tags: vb.net, function

I've searched but couldn't find anything about.

I want to know the difference between:

`Hex()` and `Hex$()`

and

`CInt()` and `Convert.ToInt32()` -Using One or the other has changed the result of some values inside my application, and i want to know when use one or the other.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Hex()` returns a variant (of VarType String) and `Hex$()` returns a true String.

Source: http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?18417-hex-hex

`CInt()` is deprecated. `Int32.Parse()` is the preferred method.

Source: http://forums.asp.net/p/681608/681796.aspx

Comment: I wouldn't say `CInt` is deprecated.  It is the recommended operator for casting objects to the `Integer` type.  It's a shortened form of `CType(..., Integer)`.  Casting is a very important and common operation, certainly not deprecated.  If simple casting is exactly what you intend to do, then I would recommend using `CInt`.  The `Convert.ToInt32` method does more logic than simply casting the object, which if that's what you want, that's what you should use.

Answer (score 5):

In VB.NET there is no real difference between `Hex()` and `Hex$()` - they both call the same function. The dollar sign just states that the function will return a string (which it already does). There used to be a distinction in the old VB, but that's long gone now.

There are subtle differences between `CInt ()` and `Convert.ToInt32 ()` / `Int32.Parse ()`, [here](http://www.panopticoncentral.net/2004/06/07/conversion-operators-in-vb/) is a very good post about this. Personally I use either `CInt` or `Int32.Parse` depending on the input - the former for numeric conversions (Long to Integer for instance, as the post explains `CInt` is substantially faster in this case), and the latter for string conversions ("123" to Integer, because it's easier to specify culture/formatting options).